RabbitMQ docker: Cannot access management
I've got the docker compose
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

And I used an example .net application to connect to rabbitMq
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;

var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "logs", type: ExchangeType.Fanout);

var message = GetMessage(args);
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "logs",
                     routingKey: string.Empty,
                     basicProperties: null,
                     body: body);
Console.WriteLine($" [x] Sent {message}");

Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();

static string GetMessage(string[] args)
{
    return ((args.Length > 0) ? string.Join(" ", args) : "info: Hello World!");
}

When running this code I can see in the rabbitMQ logs is accepting the connections
2024-09-17 14:42:52 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:42:52.470395+00:00 [info] <0.920.0> connection <0.920.0> (172.25.0.1:35338 -> 172.25.0.2:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2024-09-17 14:43:16 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:43:16.385230+00:00 [info] <0.920.0> closing AMQP connection <0.920.0> (172.25.0.1:35338 -> 172.25.0.2:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest')

But when navigating to http://localhost:15672/ I just get HTTP ERROR 431
With no connection the logs just end with at
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0> Server startup complete; 5 plugins started.
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0>  * rabbitmq_prometheus
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0>  * rabbitmq_federation
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0>  * rabbitmq_management
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0>  * rabbitmq_management_agent
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.629076+00:00 [info] <0.712.0>  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
2024-09-17 14:36:34 rabbitmq  | 2024-09-17 13:36:34.790813+00:00 [info] <0.9.0> Time to start RabbitMQ: 6453 ms

I have been able to access the management page but only through 127.0.0.1 strangely. So if anyone know why I can only access it from there that would be a help. (I can access other docker containers from localhost)

For reproducing this behavior, some logging would be nice..... (In other works when following some online how-to thing. see: https://i.sstatic.net/J71cdQ2C.png )

No logs are produced by RabbitMQ when I go to http://localhost:15672/, if I don't send a message the logs end at [updated on the question]

Could you link the same how to you used, see if I can get it working from that howto?

https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/   (But I used: https://www.architect.io/blog/2021-01-19/rabbitmq-docker-tutorial/ )

Followed that, even get the log message [info] <0.778.0> Management plugin: HTTP (non-TLS) listener started on port 15672
But still doesn't work for me. Must me something on my machine that is stopping the management portal...

Interestingly it only works if I access it from 127.0.0.1

ping -4 localhost should reply with 127.0.0.1, if not you have found your problem.

ping -4 localhost does reply with 127.0.0.1
